# Using poppler as a subproject in Cmake with `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` set incorrectly

Tags: c++, cmake, poppler

I'm new to CMake to I'm not sure what I'm doing

I'm using poppler as a library via CMake for my application. I've imported it as a submodule.

If I include popper in my top-level CMake file using `add_subdirectory(...)`, it get the following errors

```sh
[cmake] CMake Error at external/poppler/CMakeLists.txt:7 (include):
[cmake]   include could not find requested file:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     PopplerDefaults
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at external/poppler/CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
```

This is most likely because the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is incorrect.

After some digging, it looks like poppler is setting the module path instead of appending to it.

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L5

So I can't really override it it seems.

My (probably overly complicated) setup is here, which the poppler line commented out.
https://github.com/bdurrani/cmake-test/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L69

This works fine if I run cmake from within the poppler folder.

Is there a way around this? How to you handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in  *your CMakeLists.txt* just store and restore the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH before including the subproject.

```
set(tmp ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
add_subdirectory(...)
# suffix the poppler stuff too.
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${tmp};${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
```

You could also separately notify developers of the `poppler` project of the issue, or at best create a patch for them that Will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid making any changes to poppler for this. Just to be clear, I would need to make this change in poppler's CMake file and not my own, right?

Comment: `this change` What change? Ideally, poppler would do `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/somewhere")`

Comment: The change where I store and restore the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.
Yeah, I'll ping those guys on their mailing list. This might not be a use case they intend on supporting. 
Thanks for your help.